# Copying array into workbook which is part of a collection gives run time error 451 in VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, class

as part of some VBA for Excel that I'm writing I would like to print a 12 x 101 element array (`dwt_percentiles`) that is part of an item in a collection to a workbook so that I can make some graphs from the data. I have only started using classes in VBA in the past 24 hours and have got stuck on the following issue:

The line in the function where I am attempting to print the array throws the following error: "Runtime error 451: Property let procedure not defined and property get procedure did not return an object". The `dwt_percentiles` array is showing up fine with expected values when I add colltasks to the watches window, but I can't seem to access it from the code. I can access the other properties of the items of the collection fine, so it's probably an error in how I'm trying to access the array, but I can't find any similar code to what I'm attempting online (probably because I use the wrong terminology...).

The code I'm using is as follows:

Function `plotECDF`

```
Sub plotECDF(ByVal colltasks As Collection)

    Dim item As Variant
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer
    
    For i = 7 To 13
        Sheet3.Range("A1").Value = i
        Sheet3.Range("B1").Value = colltasks(i).Name
        
        For j = 1 To 12
            For k = 0 To 100
                ' error shown on next line - run time error 451
                Sheet3.Cells(1 + j, 3 + k).Value = colltasks(i).dwt_percentiles(j, k)
            Next k
        Next j
                
    Next
    
End Sub
```

Class module `Task` - tasks form the elements of a collection

```
Option Explicit

' Basic properties
Public Name As String
Public Hs As Double
Public Ws As Double
Public window As Double

' Array definitions
Public dwt_array As Variant
Public dwt_byMonth As Variant
Public dwt_percentiles As Variant
```

Code which creates dwt_percentiles() array and sticks it in a collection

```
Sub do_things()

Dim percentileByMonth() As Variant
Dim percentileSum As Double
Dim percentileArray() As Variant
Dim numYears as Integer, j as Integer, jj as Integer, k as Integer
Dim t as New Task
Dim colltasks as New Collection

percentileSum = 0
ReDim percentilesByMonth(1 To 12, 0 To 100)
For j = 1 To 12
   For jj = 0 To 100
      For k = 1 To numYears + 1
         percentileSum = percentileSum + percentileArray(j, k, jj)
      Next k
                
      percentilesByMonth(j, jj) = percentileSum / (numYears + 1)
      percentileSum = 0

    Next jj
Next j

t.dwt_percentiles = percentilesByMonth

End sub
```

Many thanks.

Comment: You can just paste an array in, so `range("a1").resize(y,x).value=array(y,x)` does `Public dwt_percentiles() As Variant` help

Comment: Please [show how](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) you initialize your `Task` and put it into collection.

Comment: @GSerg, have done it now, sorry for the confusion. @Nathan_Sav - when I put brackets around the `dwt_percentiles` array, I get a compile error: "Constants, fixed-length strings, arrays, user-defined types and declare statements are not allowed as Public members of object modules".

Comment: VBA sometimes gets confused wrt objects vs variants vs arrays, especially when hidden within collections, and it's not clear here where in the reference chain that it's getting confused.  Try replacing the offending line with this code: `Dim tsk As Task
:Set tsk = colltasks(i)
:Dim pct() As Variant
:pct = tsk.dwt_percentiles
:Sheet3.Cells(1 + j, 3 + k).Value = pct(j, k)`  and then let us know which lines throws an error. (change the colons to line-breaks).  NOTE: There's an outside chance that this may fix it or change it to a different error.

Comment: @RBarryYoung, thank you, in the end I wrote a public procedure to get the values out of the `dwt_array` and used that procedure in the main subroutine in a loop to get the result I wanted. Thank you for your help